# VBA script to edit rows of only the new data from another workbook that was pasted below existing data of current workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a script that is periodically used to copy new data (in tabular form) from another workbook to be pasted directly below the data of my current workbook with this:

```
Public Sub Copy()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim CopyLastRow As Long
Dim DestLastRow As Long

Set wsCopy = Workbooks("file1.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet 1")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("file2.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet 2")

CopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(x1Up).Row
DestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(x1Up).Row.Offset(1).Row

Copy.Range("A2:V" & CopyLastRow).Copy_
wsDest.Range ("A" & DestLastRow)

End Sub
```

I want to add on to that macro script such that for each row of new data that was pasted:

- Columns L to O are shifted one cell to the right
- Fill the now empty Column L with the value "IN"
- And then delete the data from Column Q to S

These changes are only supposed to affect the new rows of data.

But I'm not sure how to reference the new data when there is existing data on top. Furthermore, the number of entries for new data is not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use some Range variables, something like this

```vb
Dim rCopy As Range
Dim rDest As Range 

Set rCopy = wsCopy.Range("A2:V" & CopyLastRow)
Set rDest = wsDest.Range ("A" & DestLastRow)

rCopy.Copy rDest

Set rDest = rDest.Resize(rCopy.Rows.Count, rCopy.Columns.Count)

'Then apply your modifications to rDest
rDest.Columns(12).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
rDest.Columns(12).Value = "IN"
rDest.Columns(17).Resize(, 3).Clear
```

Note, some of your descriptions of how you want to modify the data are a little unclear.  You may need to adjust some of the offsets to get exactly what you want

Comment: Thanks for your help, everything is mostly working except that rDest.Columns("L:O").Insert Shift:=xlToRight is giving me an error of "Insert Method of Range class failed"

Comment: Firstly, that's not what I suggested.  Secondly,  what _exactly_ did you expect that Insert to do?

Comment: Shift values in columns L to O for only the new rows of data one cell to the right

Comment: Firstly, `rDest.Columns("L:O").Insert` works for me.  If you are getting an error there must be something else going on in your sheet.  Secondly `rDest.Columns("L:O").Insert` doesn't do what you expect.  It inserts **4** columns, and moves **all** columns from `L` onwards 4 cellst to the right.

Comment: How best to correct this depends on your sheet layout.  Please edit your question to include some sample data, and your expected outcome (as text so we can copy/paste)  Also, indicate if there are any formula in the range, and if so how you want them to be affected by the manipulations.  Also, if there is Formatting, and how you want that to be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub XXX()
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("L2:L11").Value = "IN"
    Range("Q2:S10").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Note: I used Macro Recorder and removed the unnecessary lines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I forgot to mention that the worksheet would periodically be updated with new data. So I'm trying to know how to reference the row onwards with the new data and only make changes to those specific rows. When new data comes in, the row to be referenced will change. Your macro would work but it would be a one-off thing.